# SQL Query for counting occurrences of a value within one row

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Please see the following example table. I would like to count the 1's in each row. For the first row N_1 must be 3, for the second 2, then 1, then 0. In the end I would like to incorporate this into a stored procedure with the parameters Table, Columns, Value.

```
CREATE TABLE Have 
( Col1 INT NOT NULL
, Col2 INT NOT NULL
, Col3 INT NOT NULL
, N_1 INT NULL 
)
INSERT Have (Col1, Col2, Col3)
    VALUES
     (1, 1, 1)
    ,(1, 1, 2)
    ,(1, 2, 2) 
    ,(2, 2, 2)
```

Comment: It's usually a sign that your data model is wrong if you're looking for the same "kind" of data in multiple columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
select Col1, Col2, Col3,
case when col1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
case when col2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
case when col3 = 1 then 1 else 0 end as N_1
 from Have
```

or if you need to Update the table

```
 update Have set N_1 = case when col1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
case when col2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
case when col3 = 1 then 1 else 0 end
```

then you can perform

```
select * from Have
```

Comment: A suggestion for AlexDPC would be to create the `N_1` column as a computed column

Comment: Thanks, this is what I aimed for. Computed column is not an alternative, because neither the columns to include in the computation nor the value are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Is this generic proc what you are after?

```
CREATE proc p_count
@table sysname, @columns nvarchar(max), @value nvarchar(max), @separator char(1) = ','
-- expected format of @columns is comma separated names
-- embedded commas supported by using a different @separator
as
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 
'select *,
case when ' + replace(@columns, @separator, '=' + QuoteName(@value,'''') +
' then 1 else 0 end + case when ') + '=' + QuoteName(@value,'''') + ' then 1 else 0 end
from ' + quotename(@table)
--print @sql
exec (@sql)
GO
```

Usage:

```
exec p_count 'have', 'col1|[col2]|col3', 1, '|'
exec p_count 'have', 'col1,col2,col3', 1
```

This alternate version will take an optional parameter and update the column in the same table with the count.

```
CREATE proc p_count
@table sysname, @columns nvarchar(max), @value nvarchar(max), @separator char(1) = ',', @updateto sysname = null
-- expected format of @columns is comma separated names
-- embedded commas supported by using a different @separator
as
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 
case when @updateto is null then 'select' else 'update x set ' + quotename(@updateto) + '=' end +
' case when ' + replace(@columns, @separator, '=' + QuoteName(@value,'''') +
' then 1 else 0 end + case when ') + '=' + QuoteName(@value,'''') + ' then 1 else 0 end
from ' + quotename(@table) + ' x'
print @sql
exec (@sql)
GO
```

Usage (update N_1):

```
exec p_count 'have', 'col1,col2,col3', 1, ',', 'N_1'
select * from have
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake on your query bilnil, should be

```
select *, 
( case Col1 when 1 then 1 else 0 end ) +
( case Col2 when 1 then 1 else 0 end ) +
( case Col3 when 1 then 1 else 0 end ) 
from have
```

Comment: This one calculates an extra column instead of filling N_1.